# DataGridDragDropTarget: Change Icon depending on the drop target

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, silverlight-5.0, silverlight-toolkit

I'm currently writing a tool to assign entities from one `DataGrid` to entities in another `DataGrid` via drag-and-drop.
With some fiddling, I got everything to run smoothly, with one minor annoyance: Some entities cannot be assigned to some other entities, which isn't reflected by the UI (yet).

So, the behavior I want to achieve is the following: When the user drags the assignee over the other entity, the icon should change to the "you can't drop that here" icon if the entities aren't compatible.

This is my code (attached to the `DataGridDragDropTarget.DragOver` event of the target `DataGrid`):

```
private void DragDropTarget_OnDragOver(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
{
    var sw = sender as DataGridDragDropTarget;

    if (sw == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(GetAssignmentCondition(e))
    {
        // TODO: Show link-icon
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: Show drop-disabled-icon
    }
}
```

What I've tried so far:

I've set `e.Effects`, the `DragDropTarget`'s `AllowedSourceEffects` property and the underlying `ItemDragEventArgs`'s `AllowedEffects` and `Effects` to `DragDropEffects.None`, to no avail. Googling also didn't yield any meaningful results, and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helps in situations with `TextBox` and `FlowDocument` controls, so it should work with `DataGrid`.

The key here is to set the event to `Handled` to keep the control from doing its shenanigans.

Something like so:

Code behind (just for demonstration - preferably use a more MVVM friendly solution):

```
private void DragDropTarget_DragEnter(object sender, Microsoft.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
{
    var sw = sender as DataGridDragDropTarget;

    if (sw == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    if(GetAssignmentCondition(e))
    {
        // TODO: Show link-icon
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Link;
    }
    else
    {
        // TODO: Show drop-disabled-icon
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    // Add this
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the `Preview*` events don't exist in silverlight. I will try setting `e.Handled` to true, though, and see if that helps.

Comment: Did setting it to `Handled` work?  MS really did Drag and Drop poorly with XAML, and I've run into this issue in several ways, usually with lots of pain - so I try to reduce others' pain.  (Apologies for missing the very obvious `Silverlight` tags).

Comment: Oh, and maybe you should edit your answer to actually make the code work for SL, for others who encounter the same problem.

Comment: Sweet!  Glad it worked!  I'll do a fixer-upper on it after I get off work.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `Effects` property of `DragEventArgs`  in the `OnDragOver` event handler without setting the `Handled` property to 'true' does not works because as you can see here in the [DragDropTarget.cs](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#779729) source code. If `OnDragOver` is not handled (`args.Handled=true;`) in any of event handlers, the `args.Effects` will revert back to `args.AllowedEffects`.

```
    protected virtual void OnDragOver(SW.DragEventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (SW.DragEventHandler handler in _dragOver)
        {
            handler(this, args);
            if (args.Handled)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        OnDragEvent(args);
    }

    protected virtual void OnDragEvent(SW.DragEventArgs args)
    {
        SW.DragDropEffects effects = args.AllowedEffects;

        ///removed for clarity

        if (!args.Handled && effects != args.AllowedEffects)
        {
            args.Effects = effects;  // revert back to args.AllowedEffects
            args.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```